# Dismiss UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have tried every variation of dismissing a UIImagePickerController with out any luck. What am i doing wrong.

```
- (IBAction)choosePhoto
{
    self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:YES];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker
{
    NSLog(@"dismiss image picker");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [[self.picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.presentedViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
     // And every other way i could think of
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    .. same stuff here
}
```

I have tried to present the picker from the parent, grandparent, navigationController and root controller and nothing works. What ever i do i cant dismiss the ImagePickerController.

Please note the log statement gets called every time.

Cheers

Comment: have you try [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; ?

Comment: Yeh, doesn't work. I should add im using a storyboard and arc

Comment: have you double checked that the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate are set in your .h file?

Comment: Yes they are and the imagePickerControllerDidCancel is definitely being called.

Comment: are you sure that you try  [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; because this line is not on your list?

Comment: I had actually changed the bundle identifier. So when i was launching the application it was calling the existing application not the new one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Try this line. It might work for you.**

```
[self.picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

And for **iOS 6** and later use this

```
[self.picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Also use this code to present your picker controller

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]){
    [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    //To target iOS 5.0
    [self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you running iOS 6? If so, `presentModalViewController:` is deprecated and could be causing some unexpected results. Try using `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead.

But technically, here's all you should have to do:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker
{
   [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];//Or call YES if you want the nice dismissal animation
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For Swift use this:

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController!) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 4:

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: One should update already provided answer, instead of adding new one.